# Как узнать полный путь к выбраному файлу через <input type="file"? HTML, jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Я делаю программу которой нужно получить картинку, это я сделал через input:

```
<div class="imgc">
    <button class="addfiles">Выберите файл для конвертирования</button>
    <input type="file" name="photo" multiple accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .ico" id="img">
</div>
```

Но у меня никак не получиться узнать полный путь к выбранной картинки. Вот мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Полезная прога</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="theme-link">
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/menu.png" height="35px" width="35px" class="menuI">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="imgc_m">
            <img src="images/img.png" height="48px" width="58px">
            <h4>Image Converter</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgc">
        <button class="addfiles">Выберите файл для конвертирования</button>
        <input type="file" name="photo" multiple accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .ico" id="img">
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            "use strict";
            // Меню гамбургер
            $('.menuI').click(function (e) {
                $('div.menu').toggleClass('show');
            })
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            "use strict";
            
            $('.imgc_m').click(function (e) {
                $('div.imgc').toggleClass('show');
            })
            $('.addfiles').click(function (e) {
                $('#img').click();
                $(function()
                {
                    $('#img').on('change',function ()
                    {
                        var filePath = $(this).val();
                        alert(filePath);
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
        window.onresize = function () 
        {
            window.resizeTo(700, 700);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: никак. запрещено требованиями  безопасности

Comment: "никак не получиться узнать полный путь к выбранной картинки" - зачем?

Comment: для полезной проги вовсе не обязательно знать полный путь к файлу

Answer (score 2):

Возможности узнать нет,а связано это с безопасностью, чтобы не передавать информацию об устройстве вашей файловой системы,как видно в снипете вставляется фейковый путь, у меня это `C:\fakepath\` не смотря на то что я на Linux.

```html
<input type="file" onchange="console.log(this.value);">
```